# column aligment for flex element with max-height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

here is flex element with `flex: column wrap;` and `max-height: 150px;`. My problem is that `justify-content` not working. But working with `height: 150px`. For container with `max-width: 100%;` & `flex-direction: row;` aligment works properly

```css
.container {
  max-height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  width: 25%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Twag0.png)

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdpsW.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it's a bug or an intended result but you can fix it if you consider an extra wrapper where you apply the `max-height` property:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width:100%;
}

.item {
  width: 25%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.extra {
  max-height: 150px;
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="extra">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Worth to note that if you consider `height` instead of `max-height` it works fine:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 150px;
}

.item {
  width: 25%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```